# Created Table has a function assigning default values to NOT NULL columns.From SSIS,the default function is not getting invoked

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am trying to run an insert statement against a tables which has few NOT Null columns in it.In case the values are not assigned to those columns then a default function defined assigns the values. While i am trying to run the Insert statement from SSIS the package is failing due to NOT Null Constraint. Please suggest.

If i assign values to all the columns it is running successfully but i want the default values to be assigned automatically rather than passing every time.

Below is the tables script:
ALTER TABLE [Fee] ADD  DEFAULT ([dbo].svf_GetUser) FOR [CreatedBy]
GO

[OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CreatedBy', table 'SAI.dbo.Fee'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.".

Comment: Try not using the `Fast load` option in the destination `Data Access Mode`. Also try to uncheck the `Check constraint` checkbox in the destination.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing null into insert statment then it will error out by giving can not insert null into Not null column but if your insert statement is like 
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2,COL3) VALUES(1,2, NULL) then remove that column(COL3)from here it will take default value.

Comment: I am not assigning any values to COL3. The SSIS package is unable to initiate/trigger the default value function (from package prospective) due to which the insert is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is 18mo old at the time of my reply, but I just experienced this error in an SSIS workflow I was working on, where a field in my target table was defined as:

```
[OBSERVATION_GUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT newid()
```

The table had a clustered columnstore index, so in the SSIS package I had to use "Table or View - Fast Load". The error message you describe in your question was thrown. The answer is to uncheck "Keep Nulls". I have null values in other fields of my table, but turning this option off did not effect them (like turn them to empty strings or something). It appears "Keep Nulls" really just prevents the DEFAULT override of an inserted null value to trigger.